# ClassMethods in Controller Concern returning NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror, activesupport-concern

I have created a concern in controllers/concerns called reports.rb

In it I created the ClassMethods module.. It looks like this

```
module Reports
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

included do
    require 'peddler'
    require 'csv'
end

module ClassMethods

    def report_details(token, marketplace_id, merchant_id)
      #...
    end
```

I included this concern in my Merchants controller like this:

```
class MerchantsController < ApplicationController
  include Reports
```

And then tried to call the report_details method in an action on the Merchants controller like so:

```
def pull_from_amazon
    me = Merchant.find(params[:merchant_id])
    marketplace = me.marketplace
    token = me.token
    Merchant.report_details(token, marketplace, params[:merchant_id])
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

According to this post [Rich on Rails](https://richonrails.com/articles/rails-4-code-concerns-in-active-record-models) I should be able to call:

```
Merchant.report_details(xx,xxx,xxxx)
```

But I get a NoMethodError when I try.. I also tried:

```
me.report_details(xx,xxx,xxxx)
```

And got the same NoMethodError

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you restart Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
MerchantController.report_details(xx,xxx,xxxx)
```

But you should better include this concern in model.

Comment: I tried MerchantController.report_details but it didn't work.. BUT I did include the concern in the Merchant model and then used Merchant.report_details and that worked!! Thank you much!

Comment: @ToddT, on you original question you said you include it in the controller, so Alex is right, if you do it on your model, of course that changes. Consider accepting Alex's answer.